# Instead of dotted line,Can we use solid line in JS TREE?

Tags: jstree, tree-structure

I want to use a solid line in the JS Tree structure instead of the dotted line.

Refer Screenshot

[image: jstree]

I can remove dotted line using the following code

`$('#html').jstree().hide_dots();`

But I want to change it from dotted to solid. Is there any way for it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to convert the dotted lines to a solid line. Unfortunately the lines are not text or svg. They are formed using the theme image below. If you're using the default theme, it's available in the `themes/default` directory as `32px.png`.

[image]

You can edit this image to change the tree style.